# Prove $n^{2n+1}\ge(n+1)^{n+1}(n-1)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For natural numbers—that is, integers greater than or equal to 1—prove that: 
$n^{2n+1}\ge(n+1)^{n+1}(n-1)^{n}$

Equivalently, show that  $(1-1/n)^n$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: You must show your efforts. Also $(1-\frac {1}{n}) $ is always strictly increasing over positive integers. So $(1-\frac {1}{n})^n $ is increasing.

Comment: It is really surprising that this question is being upvoted in spite of no indication of OP's efforts.

Comment: I was never able to make any progress beyond this point, unless you count a bunch of failed inductive proofs and a horrible derivative.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN f(n) increasing doesn't imply f(n)^n increasing for 0 < f(n) < 1.

Comment: Don't care if$ f (n)$ is less than 1. $ f (n)<f (n+1)$

Comment: Oh sorry I get you my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot 1\stackrel{\color{red}{AM-GM}}{\color{red}{<}}\left(\frac{n\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

One can check that it can be rearranged to

$$1-\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}$$

And this is an application of the Bernoulli inequality $1+kx\leq (1+x)^k$

Comment: Sometimes it seems that *everything* is an application of the Bernoulli inequality.

Comment: @martycohen Your one stop to shop.

Answer (score 2):

For $n \ge 2$, the first inequality is equal to

$(1 + \frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^n \ge 1 + \frac{1}{n}$.

This is obvious by the following.

$(1 + \frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^n \ge 1 + \frac{n}{n^2 - 1} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{n}$.